# Loop through all defined variables jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I want to loop through all defined variables in a jquery function for pushing corresponding variable name into an array. The code is given below

```
 function pushallvariables()
 {
    var list = [];

    var name = /^[A-Za-z\s.]+$/;
    var general = /^[A-Za-z0-9\s.\-\/]{2,20}$/;
    var email = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/;
    var digit = /^[+]?[0-9\s]+$/;

      list.push('name');
      list.push('general');
      list.push('email');
      list.push('digit');
 }
```

I want to modify this function into

```
 function pushallvariables()
 {
    var list = [];

    var name = /^[A-Za-z\s.]+$/;
    var general = /^[A-Za-z0-9\s.\-\/]{2,20}$/;
    var email = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/;
    var digit = /^[+]?[0-9\s]+$/;

    for each(variable as var)
    {
       list.push(var.name);
    }
  }
```

But the modified function is not correct. How can I write the function ?

Comment: AFAIK no, you can't do that... you can create an object with those variables are keys value pairs then iterate that object

Comment: are you crazy? `var` is the keyword of javascript. You cant use it like a variable

Comment: @ Ashish Kumar. I know. That is why I already mentioned that modified function is not correct. I just want to express the thing to be implemented, that's only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best and clear way to do that is:

```
var list = {};

list.name    = /^[A-Za-z\s.]+$/;
list.general = /^[A-Za-z0-9\s.\-\/]{2,20}$/;
list.email   = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/;
list.digit   = /^[+]?[0-9\s]+$/;
```

without loops, etc

Comment: Thank you hsz. Your Answer worked fine for my case and is the best and clear way.